# Meteor: render body tag content on first site loading (for SEO)

Tags: meteor

I want to take something like this:

```
....
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Some custom content for current route</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

instead of empty body tag:

```
....
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Time to dig into spiderable and phantomjs.

Comment: Yes, but idea is to render another content: google will see simplified content without side menu etc

Comment: or spiderable can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn how to use the [Spiderable](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable) package in your project